# How to make image resize and overlap div responsively with surrounding content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Hi need help with bootstrap framework and css in the page. Section of interest only is the top section which includes an image, image caption, graybar, and quote. See image attached for a representation.[image] At tablet sizes and larger I need the top section's image to overlap the graybar with equal distance from top and bottom, resize responsively as the screen gets larger but not past an image size of width 300px. Quote inside gray bar should also behave responsively.  I have tried transform, scale on the image, but the image caption gets hidden.

```css
  .president-section {
  background-color: #545454;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.president-details {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

blockquote {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 5%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .president-details img {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .president-section {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .president-details {
    transform: translate(-50px, -70px);
    width: 300px;
  }
  blockquote {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 26px;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    blockquote {
      font-size: 30px;
      line-height: 36px;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .quote {
      transform: translate(-100px, 0);
    }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="background-color: #e5a09c;">
  <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet cake croissant fruitcake muffin. Sweet bonbon candy powder cheesecake muffin sesame snaps jujubes. Muffin macaroon cheesecake cookie souffl&eacute; cookie cheesecake lollipop candy canes. Halvah cotton candy sesame snaps
    chocolate bar. Sugar plum dessert drag&eacute;e macaroon chupa chups. Cake cheesecake wafer cotton candy. Danish jelly halvah jelly beans tootsie roll donut. Halvah cheesecake halvah jujubes sweet roll biscuit croissant wafer. Cake halvah chocolate
    bar sugar plum apple pie.</p>


  <div class="row president-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4">
          <div class="president-details">

            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1n1Bc9Xnu6N2UEzTqXN5ZpRN_W8m6mhAG">

            <p class="president-name text-center"><strong>President's Name</strong></p>


          </div>


        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-7 col-lg-8 quote">
          <div class="row">
            <blockquote>
              &ldquo;Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet cake croissant fruitcake muffin. Sweet bonbon candy powder cheesecake muffin sesame snapsjujubes. Muffin macaroon cheesecake&rdquo; <cite>-Richard Something</cite>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <h3>Members</h3>

  <div class="row img-row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/163x240" /> <strong>Immediate Past President</strong>

      <div class="name">John Doe 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/163x240" /> <strong>Executive Director</strong>

      <div class="name">John Doe 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/163x240" /> <strong>President-Nominee</strong>

      <div class="name">John Doe 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Row 2 -->

    <div class="col-6 col-md-3"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/163x240" /> <strong>John Doe 4</strong>

      <div class="term">Term: 2019&ndash;2022</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked into Bootstrap 4's [Responsive Images](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/images/#responsive-images)

Comment: Yes, I am. However I'm trying to get the image to overlap over the graybar behind it equally from the top and bottom on tablets and larger. I've got something working but it's not elegant. I've explicitly set the height of the graybar and the image. This will not always work if the quote exceeds the height. And the quote needs to always align vertically.